# Understanding the query string after .htaccess rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, urls

I'm of the understanding that Wordpress' .htaccess, like below:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

sends all queries through to the index.php (unless the filename exists on the server etc).

So, if I go to `http://example.com/checkout` Wordpress rewrites that as `http://example.com/index.php?pagename=checkout`.

But what I don't understand is that I have, at the top of a page template

```
<?php print_r($_GET) ?>
```

and when I navigate to `http://example.com/checkout` that returns `Array()`. I'd expect something like `Array('pagename' => 'checkout')`;

How can I access the variables that Wordpress uses when handling a URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really rewriting the URL in the conventional sense, URL parsing happens entirely within PHP.

You can access the query vars in the global `$wp_query->query_vars`, or with the [`get_query_var`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) function.

Also note that [`parse_request`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/parse_request) is the earliest action where this info will be available.

Comment: these were all good answers, but the `$wp_query->query_vars` was exactly what I was looking for. My Googling kept landing me on `get_query_var` (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) which never gave me all the vars.

Answer (score 1):

It calls `index.php`, not `index.php?page=..`.

I'm not sure how WordPress does its routing, but you could use `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` or `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Answer (score 1):

Don't get fooled by the names. mod_rewrite Rewrite Rules and WordPress Rewrite Rules are two very different things.

In the .htaccess, there are mod_rewrite rules that don't do anything other than run WP's index.php for any requests that don't directly hit an existing file or directory.

To figure out, what /checkout means, WordPress then relies on its' own set of rewrite rules which have nothing at all to do with mod_rewrite, so don't get confused.

WordPress' `$redirect` part looks like it passes variables via HTTP GET, but that isn't really the case. Those will be used as rewrite tags. See the [documentation for add_rewrite_rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) for a few examples and further explanation.